# Why hasn't life on Earth reached an evolutionary stable strategy?

Tags: evolutionary-game-theory

I heard in some YouTube video that cheetahs only existed 5,000,000 years and according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction, extinctions are occurring all the time so I assume life on Earth hasn't reached an evolutionary stable strategy. I know some species like ants are in an evolutionary stable strategy and most species are close to their evolutionary stable strategy because the system of the rest of the species is changing so slowly but why hasn't the system of all life on Earth reached an evolutionary stable strategy. Could it be that it's destined to never reach one? That doesn't necessarily mean there isn't one. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_game_theory, the side blotched lizard has 3 forms undergoing cyclic evolution so it's destined to never reach an evolutionary stable strategy if the state of the rest of the species on Earth doesn't change. There's another case of cyclic evolution where rabbits outcompete wolves when there are very few rabbits and wolves outcompete rabbits when there are a lot of rabbits? Why are there so many species that have existed for no more than 5,000,000 years instead of the system of all life on Earth being stable with a few species undergoing cyclic evolution? What's causing the current state of all life on Earth to keep on not being evolutionary unstable?

Comment: The concept of ESS applies to a population (in a constant environment), not to all of living things on a planet.

Answer (score 2):

Because the environment on earth is not stable on the long run.

Antarctica was on the tropics. However plate tectonics has moved the continent from that location to south pole. And in time the continues will leave the poles and move toward the tropics again.

So a perfectly evolved animal in tropical Antarctica 200 million years ago, would have to continue evolving or it would have gone extinct as Antarctica moved southwards. And the animals living on Antarctica today will have to evolve as the continues continues with its motions.

Also predator-prey relationships... are red queen type relationship. They may appear stable on the outside, but both parties are actually under selection pressure to evolve, to counter the advantages of the other party. They are in an arms races. Pressure to out run the predator. Pressure to outwit the prey. Pressure to better camouflage. Pressure to detect prey from multiple senses (sound, sight smell).

So on the long term, the strategy that a predator uses will change as its prey evolves. And vise versa for the prey.

Comment: "are only..." what?